# VB.Net Delete last remaining row from Binding source

Tags: vb.net, delete-row, bindingsource

I am trying to delete rows from my data table through binding source. below code works and it removes the row when there are more than 1 rows. If i have a only one row it gives me an error  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Any idea why it fails on single row.

```
    Dim eqID As Int32 = dGv.Rows(dgv_selected_index).Cells(dtEQID).value
    Dim eID_Indx As Integer = EQ_BS.Find(dtEQID, eqID)
    EQ_BS.RemoveAt(eID_Indx)
```

first line of code gets the primary column value from the selected item from the datagridview
2nd line finds the index of the row of my primary key value
3 line removes (if i have more than 1 row)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using try catch..

```
Try    
   Dim eqID As Int32 = dGv.Rows(dgv_selected_index).Cells(dtEQID).value
   Dim eID_Indx As Integer = EQ_BS.Find(dtEQID, eqID)
   EQ_BS.RemoveAt(eID_Indx)
Catch
End try
```